# TMainMenu in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have two separate forms in my application. I created one additional empty form and placed a TMainMenu component on it with two menu items. This new form will serve as the main form from which everything else will be loaded. Now I want it to work like this: when you click either of the two menu items, it should load the respective form's contents the menu item associated with to the main form. How can I achieve this? Or what is the typical approach to this kind of problem? Please, provide a simple illustrative example.

[image] [image]

Comment: Use TFrame, they are made specifically for that.

Comment: I think this can be solved by a very basic tutorial. Check out [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RW9RDvpjnCg).

Comment: I looked into it. Thanks. But How do I convert my existing forms to frames?

Comment: Create a new TFrame, then copy/paste your existing TForm controls and associated code over to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to embed other form in the your main form put a tpanel in to your main form set alclient property. And when clicked set fromxxx.parent is your panel name.

here is a sample code

```
  begin
    if Dm.TblUser.Active=False then 
      Dm.TblUser.Active := True;
    if FrmPUserG=nil then 
      FrmPUserG := TFrmPUserG.Create(Self);
    FrmpUserG.Parent := PnLContainer;
    FrmpUserG.Align := alClient;
    FrmpUserG.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    FrmpUserG.Visible := True;
    FrmpUserG.BringToFront;
  end;
```

Comment: I am guessing for downvote, there is no mention of Dm variable. Also the snippet seems to be copied and pasted from some existing code.

Comment: it is from my running another program.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `TPanel` on your `MainForm` and set its `Align := alClient`, `BevelOuter := bvNone`. Also give the `MainForm` attributes `Form1: TForm1` and `Form2: TForm2`. Then display `Form1` or `Form2` in this way:

Showing `Form1`:

```
if not Assigned(MainForm.Form1) then
  MainForm.Form1 := TForm1.Create(MainForm);
MainForm.Form1.Parent := MainForm.Panel1;
MainForm.Form1.Align := alClient;
MainForm.Form1.BorderStyle := bsNone;
MainForm.Form1.Visible := True;
if Assigned(MainForm.Form2) then
  MainForm.Form2.Visible := False;
```

Of course you don't need to write `MainForm`; it's just to make the example clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of Forms already created and want to add the ability of being show "docked" you could change the inheritance to a new template instead of TFrom.
By adding and overloaded constructor you will be able to use them as usual or "docked".
To change the inheritance you only have to replace

```
type
  TYourForm = class(TForm)
```

with

```
type
  TYourForm = class(TTemplate)
```

and replace the `object` in your DMF's with `inherited`

```
{
  public
    Constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent;AParent:TWinControl=nil);Overload;
.....
}
constructor TTemplate.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if Assigned(AParent) then
    begin
      BorderStyle := bsNone;
      Parent := AParent;
      Align := alClient;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Though inheritance might be neat, what I don't like about this solution is that you make the forms aware of this embedding while there is completely no need for that.